# sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin fails on jammy

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The Ubuntu machine contains the latest upgrades, but unable to install docker-compose-plugin

```
sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-compose-plugin


cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I followed the official installation guide and it worked. I think my keyrings was outdated or something.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

```
# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```

> Note:
>
> If you use an Ubuntu derivative distro, such as Linux Mint, you may need to  use UBUNTU_CODENAME instead of VERSION_CODENAME.

```
# Remember to start the docker container after installation by running
$: sudo service docker start
```